# My computer wakes up at 5:59:39 every morning. How do I stop that from happening?

Tags: sleep-wake, power-management

For some reason my 2017 iMac running macOS 10.14.6 keeps waking up from sleep at exactly 5:59:39 AM every morning. If I look at the logs using `pmset -g log` at this time it consistently reports:

```
2019-11-07 05:59:39 -0500 Assertions            PID 77(powerd) Created UserIsActive "com.apple.powermanagement.wakeschedule" 00:00:00  id:0x0x900009fac [System: PrevIdle PrevDisp DeclUser kDisp]
2019-11-07 05:59:39 -0500 Assertions            Kernel Idle sleep preventers: IODisplayWrangler
2019-11-07 05:59:39 -0500 Notification          Display is turned on
2019-11-07 05:59:40 -0500 Assertions            PID 77(powerd) Created UserIsActive "com.apple.powermanagement.wakeschedule" 00:00:00  id:0x0x900009faf [System: PrevIdle PrevDisp DeclUser kDisp]
2019-11-07 05:59:41 -0500 Assertions            PID 77(powerd) TimedOut UserIsActive "com.apple.powermanagement.wakeschedule" 00:00:02  id:0x0x900009fac [System: PrevIdle PrevDisp DeclUser kDisp]
2019-11-07 05:59:41 -0500 Assertions            PID 77(powerd) TimedOut UserIsActive "com.apple.powermanagement.wakeschedule" 00:00:01  id:0x0x900009faf [System: PrevIdle PrevDisp DeclUser kDisp]
```

I don't understand what those log entries mean and searching for the terms in them hasn't yielded anything revealing so far.

In the Energy Saver system preferences, I have the following options enabled:

- Prevent Computer from sleeping automatically when the display is off
- Wake for network access
- Enable Power Nap

In the "Schedule" settings the "Start up or wake" setting is **disabled**.

Why is my computer waking up? And what can I do to stop it?

Comment: In Terminal, type `pmset -g sched`, and comment with the results. There will be no result if there is nothing scheduled. If there is something scheduled it may read `Repeating power events:  wakepoweron at 5:59AM every day`.

Comment: Sure enough, one event: `wake at 11/10/19 05:59:40 by 'com.bombich.ccchelper'` Looks like Carbon Copy Cloner is the culprit.

Comment: @IconDaemon If you post your tip of using `pmset -g sched` as an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the Terminal command `pmset -g sched` to determine if there is any repeated wake from sleep scheduled or some other app/system service which has set a wake event.